# Clipboard processing in Gutenburg

Tags: block-editor

When WordPress was just using TinyMCE for its editor, it seems that there was [a pretty straightforward manner](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_preprocess) of inserting custom code into the processing that would occur after the user requested to paste something into the editor.

It's a brave new world, and the Gutenburg editor is the new (and future) standard for WordPress content editing.

My question is: **Is there currently (April 2019) a way for me to filter text that is pasted into the Gutenburg block editor as it is being pasted** (as opposed to during the saving process, for example, with the `content_save_pre` hook)?

In an attempt to answer this question, I spent a lot of time sifting through the Gutenburg editor code yesterday, particularly the part that processes pasting.

It (unsurprisingly) is very involved, but from what I could find, it does not seem that there is any equivalent to the `paste_preprocess` hook that there was (and is) in TinyMCE.

I am not willing to edit my copy of core WordPress to get the behavior I want out of Gutenburg; obviously plugins are the alternative designed for customizing WordPress' behavior, so I would like to go that route; I'm just not sure there is actually a plugin route available here.

Do I need to go straight to the top with a feature request? Or am I missing something?